# Simple Login Page using Bootstrap

Tags: html

I cant seem to make this work. I wanted a simple responsive login page but the form doesn't stay on the center, it keeps going to the left.

Why this is not working?? If I divide the col into 3 sections of 4, should the it stay on the middle?

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Login</title>
  </head>
<body style="background-color: #4b5257">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="col-lg-4"></div>
    <div class="col-lg-4">
      <div class="jumbotron" style="margin-top:150px">
        <h3>Please login</h3>
        <form action="Dashboard.jsp">
          <div class="form-group">
            <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Username">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter password">
          </div>
          <div class="custom-checkbox">
            <label><input type="checkbox"> Remember me</label>
          </div>
          <button type="submit" class="btn-primary form-control">Login</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4"></div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Well, tested on `IE11`,`Chrome 60` and `Firefox 50`, it works.

Comment: lol it doesnt on my chrome. wth

Comment: it also doesnt work on my firefox. Look how it looks https://gyazo.com/081bced9b4a4c36e27c350eaa3230b0d

Comment: Probably `col-lg-*` doesn't match your viewport, try with something smaller, like `col-sm-*`. Also, you can avoid adding 3 cols by using `col-lg-offset-*`

Comment: it only works if the browser windows is small.

Comment: what do you mean avoid adding 3 cols? How do I implement that?

Comment: sm is even worse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've added a class named col-centered. You can see an example below.

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Login</title>
    
<style>
    .col-centered{
    float: none;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
</style>
  </head>
<body style="background-color: #4b5257">
  <div class="container">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-centered">
  <div class="jumbotron">
        <h3>Please login</h3>
        <form action="Dashboard.jsp">
          <div class="form-group">
            <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Username">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter password">
          </div>
          <div class="custom-checkbox">
            <label><input type="checkbox"> Remember me</label>
          </div>
          <button type="submit" class="btn-primary form-control">Login</button>
        </form>
      </div>
  </div>
  
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```